# How to grep in a file using upper and lower values from another file in unix

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, date

I would like to ask how to grep in a certain file that contains filenames, criteria  for grep will come from another file.
Example:

fileA.txt contains:

```
newFile0001_1573001341083_123_0.txt
newFile0002_1573001341207_134_0.txt
newFile0003_1573415111000_251_0.txt
newFile0004_1999999999991_238_0.txt
newFile0005_1573002061581_305_0.txt
```

fileB.txt contains:

```
870752450724347692,2019-11-11 00:12:17,1573411337,1573407737,1573414937
870423450725349173,2019-11-11 00:21:08,1573411868,1573408268,1573415468
868909450732354559,2019-11-11 00:56:43,1573414003,1573410403,1573417603
```

where 2nd column is date/time,

3rd column is date/time in epoch,

4th column is date/time -1hr in epoch,

5th column is date/time +1hr in epoch.

-

How do I grep in fileA.txt (get each matching newFile0000_XXXXXXXXXX000_000_0.txt)

using 4th column (lower limit) and 5th column (upper limit) as range from each line in fileB.txt?

So from the example, fileA.txt 3rd entry should be fetched based from fileB.txt 2nd entry.

Comment: For this task, `grep` is not the right tool. This would require something like a shell script with two loops, one inside the other: the outer loop would parse `fileB.txt`, one line at a time, and find the lower and upper limits for each search. Then the inner loop would read `fileA.txt`, one line at a time, pick out just the timestamp on the line, compare it numerically to the limits found by the outer loop, and based on that, make a decision whether to output the line from `fileA.txt` or not.

Comment: hi @telcoM, that is what i have tried so far but it's taking time. i am reducing it now to just browsing through each line in `fileB.txt` and directly grep in `fileA.txt` given the conditions but i am having a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR { myArray[$0]=substr($0,13,10); next } 
                 { for (file in myArray) {
                       if (myArray[file]>=$4 && myArray[file]<=$5) 
                           { print file; delete myArray[file] }
                       }
                 }' fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

Alternative using multiple separators. Change the first code-block to:

```c
NR==FNR { myArray[$0] = $2/1000; next }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk '...awk-script...' FS=_ fileA.txt FS=, fileB.txt
```

Comment: hi @αғsнιη, i have tried your suggestion in a bash script but it's not working

Comment: it's not returning anything, i have declared `fileA='pwd'/fileA.txt` and `fileB='pwd'/fileB.txt` then used `$fileA $fileB` at the last line... i have also tried renaming the files as is to `fileA fileB`, still not returning anything. i really appreciate your help on this :)

Comment: with `'pwd'/fileA.txt` I'm assuming you mean backticks `\`pwd\`/fileA.txt`, right? and for files you only need to pass your fileA.txt mentioned in your question as first file and fileB.txt in your question as second file, both in last line only in command above (it was my fault I mentioned array name same as files' name)

Comment: yes, i used backticks. with the updated suggestion, no result is being shown. note that i am putting it in a bash script